# Getting "Cannot find module 'colors/safe'" error when running npm start

Tags: node.js, node-modules, npm-start

I had to clone the repository of a project to build his backend but when run the npm run start command, I have an error. I precise that the folder I've clone is furnished by my teacher so I didn't touch it before and also that it's my first backend project ever.

I have this error on my terminal :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'colors/safe'
Require stack:
- /Users/an/Documents/PROJETS/tp-go-fullstack/frontend/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/an/Documents/PROJETS/tp-go-fullstack/frontend/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server:5:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/an/Documents/PROJETS/tp-go-fullstack/frontend/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server'
  ]
}
```

Here is my package.json file (who visibly contain colors) :

```
{
  "name": "go-fullstack-v3-fr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx http-server . -p 4200 -P \"http://localhost:4200?\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "http-server": "^13.0.1"
  }
}
```

and it also appear in my package-lock.json file like this :

```
node_modules/colors": {
      "version": "1.4.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/-/colors-1.4.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-a+UqTh4kgZg/SlGvfbzDHpgRu7AAQOmmqRHJnxhRZICKFUT91brVhNNt58CMWU9PsBbv3PDCZUHbVxuDiH2mtA==",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.1.90"
      }
    },
```

I have already tried some of the answers I found for this error but I can't get rid of it.  I've tried to uninstall and reinstall the project, update colors too (it's actually the latest version 1.4.0).
Here is my version of Node.js : 18.16.0
My version of npm : 9.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file, then rerun `npm install`, then make an audit fix and finally the npm run start command work.